# Flutter RawKeyboardListener Fetching Double Inputs FromUSB RFID Reader

Tags: flutter, rfid

I am trying to get rfid data from usb rfid but the keyboard raw listerner reads the data in doubles
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx6c0.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx6c0.png
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecfap.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecfap.png

I am trying to get rfid data from usb rfid but the keyboard raw listerner reads the data in doubles

[image]

[image]